# pass empty for booleans in sql.NullBool or does it always default to true or false

Tags: postgresql, go, coalesce

empty strings are "" and empty ints are 0. Is there a way to represent an empty boolean? or does all empty booleans default to false? Because this is the behaviour i have noticed in Golang and postman. In postman formdata for example 1 represents true while an empty value represents false. I am trying to do an update of values in a psql table. The booleans are a headache for me. The sql.NullBool when using Valid: true, if i dont specify the values of the boolean it defaults to false. Is it possible to make this update function ignore the row when it is not selected for update?

```
    arg := db.UpdateProductParams{
        ID:          t,
        Name:        sql.NullString{String: req.Name, Valid: req.Name != ""},
        Description: sql.NullString{String: req.Description, Valid: req.Description != ""},
        Price:       sql.NullString{String: req.Price, Valid: req.Price != ""},
        IsKids:      sql.NullBool{Bool: req.Kids, Valid: true},
        IsWomen:     sql.NullBool{Bool: req.Women, Valid: true},
        IsMen:       sql.NullBool{Bool: req.Men, Valid: true},
    }

-- name: UpdateProduct :one
UPDATE products
SET
  name = COALESCE(sqlc.narg(name), name),
  price= COALESCE(sqlc.narg(price), price),
  description = COALESCE(sqlc.narg(description), description),
  is_kids = COALESCE(sqlc.narg(is_kids), is_kids),
  is_men = COALESCE(sqlc.narg(is_men), is_men),
  is_women = COALESCE(sqlc.narg(is_women), is_women)
WHERE
  id = sqlc.arg(id)
RETURNING *;
```

I use sqlc to generate the crud function

```
const updateProduct = `-- name: UpdateProduct :one
UPDATE products
SET
  name = COALESCE($1, name),
  price= COALESCE($2, price),
  description = COALESCE($3, description),
  is_kids = COALESCE($4, is_kids),
  is_men = COALESCE($5, is_men),
  is_women = COALESCE($6, is_women)
WHERE
  id = $7
RETURNING id, name, owner, price, rating, description, imgs_url, imgs_name, discount, discount_price, sold, is_promoted, is_trending, is_men, is_women, is_kids, created_at, tsv
`

type UpdateProductParams struct {
    Name        sql.NullString `json:"name"`
    Price       sql.NullString `json:"price"`
    Description sql.NullString `json:"description"`
    IsKids      sql.NullBool   `json:"is_kids"`
    IsMen       sql.NullBool   `json:"is_men"`
    IsWomen     sql.NullBool   `json:"is_women"`
    ID          int64          `json:"id"`
}

func (q *Queries) UpdateProduct(ctx context.Context, arg UpdateProductParams) (Product, error) {
    row := q.db.QueryRowContext(ctx, updateProduct,
        arg.Name,
        arg.Price,
        arg.Description,
        arg.IsKids,
        arg.IsMen,
        arg.IsWomen,
        arg.ID,
    )
    var i Product
    err := row.Scan(
        &i.ID,
        &i.Name,
        &i.Owner,
        &i.Price,
        &i.Rating,
        &i.Description,
        pq.Array(&i.ImgsUrl),
        pq.Array(&i.ImgsName),
        &i.Discount,
        &i.DiscountPrice,
        &i.Sold,
        &i.IsPromoted,
        &i.IsTrending,
        &i.IsMen,
        &i.IsWomen,
        &i.IsKids,
        &i.CreatedAt,
        &i.Tsv,
    )
    return i, err
}
```

Is it possible to ignore updating values of the boolean values not selected for update? Other values like the name and price can be left empty on update and the values wont change. I really hope my question is clear. Will appreciate any help.

Comment: Read [Golang What is Truth?](https://www.curiouslychase.com/notes/golang-what-is-truth/).  You also seem to be conflating False and Null. Null is neither True or False it is unknown.

Comment: In Go each type has a **zero value** (what you inaccurately refer to as "empty"). For boolean types that zero value *is* indeed `false`. https://go.dev/ref/spec#The_zero_value

Comment: What you can do, instead of setting `sql.NullBool.Valid` to `true` indiscriminately, you should set `sql.NullBool.Valid` to `true` or `false` based on whether the user specified those kids/men/women values in the request or not. When `sql.NullBool.Valid` is `false` the driver will send `NULL` to the database which, thanks to the use of `COALESCE`, will cause the the query not to change the old value.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I will surely go through the link you sent. Thanks for the recommedation.

Comment: @mkopriva i already tried setting it to true or false using **IsKids:      sql.NullBool{Bool: req.Kids, Valid: true || false} and i still get the same result**

Comment: @pythonGo The expression `true || false` always results in `true`, essentially it's identical to `Valid: true`. In my previous comment did you miss the part *"... **based on** whether the user specified those kids/men/women values in the request or not"*?

Comment: i assumed that what you meant by this was to use an **OR** operator "you should set sql.NullBool.Valid to true or false" . Maybe i don't understand what you meant or how to set it to true or false. Do you mean ``sql.NullBool{Bool: req.Kids, Valid: req.Kids == false || true} `` ?